# Does machine learning on random situations require a cryptographically-secure random number generator?

Tags: machine-learning, random-variable, random-generation, games

I'm working on a project involving using machine learning to figure out optimal strategies to play board games, and after a few rolls of the virtual dice a thought hit me:

For the games that involve randomness, such as those with dice, there can be significant value in predicting future dice rolls. And the rolls themselves are not, of course, truly random. Given this, do I reasonably have to fear that after learning through all the low-hanging fruit as far as gameplay is concerned, my ML models may try to optimize for the specific random number generator I am using, such as by predicting future rolls?

If so, would a cryptographically-secure random number generator be necessary to obviate this, or are there computationally-cheaper alternatives that offer the same protection from ML "gaming the system" in this way?

Comment: A sloppy pRNG for online poker undermined the security of the game. Importantly, you only have to know how to deduce the pRNG seed to get a game-breaking edge; you don't have to use machine learning to approximate the modulus function itself. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b0b5/7844eab28f3639a419b9d322a9a74a0498bf.pdf

Answer (score 6):

****Edit:** My original answer below is mostly informal, but I want to address some of the comments in a more technical and hopefully convincing manner. Please see the technical appendix for these details.**

Does machine learning on random situations require a cryptographically secure random number generator, or in other words, is it reasonable to fear that your machine learning algorithm will learn how to predict the output of your pseudo-random number generator (PRNG)? **Generally, no.**

Could a machine learning model such as a neural network emulate a PRNG? By this, I mean: could the function $f$ that produces the sequence of pseudo-random numbers be in the class of functions $V$ that the machine learning model is capable of representing. **Possibly**, depending on the model in question.

Could a capable machine learning model accidentally be trained from data generated by the PRNG to predict the output. **Almost certainly not**, though the probability of this is non-zero. Could we successfully create and train a custom machine learning model with the sole purpose of predicting the output of a PRNG? **Also probably not, at least not without a great deal of "cheating."**

The key point is that even if a machine learning model is capable of representing the PRNG, it has to be capable of finding the right parameters to predict the output of the PRNG. **Training a machine learning model to predict the output of a PRNG is an extremely difficult task, bordering on the impossible.** To understand why, let's first talk about how a PRNG works.

### Pseudo-Random Number Generation

Most PRNGs use some form of congruential algorithm which involves starting with a positive integer $X_0$ called the *seed* and then making a recursive sequence according to a rule similar to

$$X_{n + 1} = g(X_n) \text{ mod } m$$

for some function $g$ and constant $m \in \mathbb{N}$. There are some slight variations on the method, and of course some methods which are completely different, such as cellular automata-based methods (like Wolfram's Mathematica uses by default). To answer your question, I'm going to focus on one of the simplest PRNGs: the *linear congruential method*, which uses the function $g(x) = ax + c$ for some integer constants $a$ and $c$. This method is used by the Java programming language, even though it has relatively poor statistically properties. I'm then going to appeal to intuition to claim that, if we don't have to worry about a machine learning algorithm learning how to predict the output of a very simple PRNG with poor statistical properties, we probably don't have to worry about it learning how to predict the output of a fancy PRNG with better statistical properties.

Now, let's consider the actual constants $a$, $c$, and $m$ to use. There are various properties that these need to satisfy to make a good PRNG that I won't discuss (see Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* vol. 2 which is an authoritative treatment of the topic). Let's just consider the constants that Java's PRNG uses as a real-world example. From the source code ([on line 173](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html)), the values it uses are $a = 25214903917$, $c = 11$, and $m = 2^{48} = 281474976710656$. We also can't forget that in trying to learn the output of the PRNG, the machine learning model will also have to learn the seed $X_0$.

### Learning the $x$ mod $m$ Function is Hard

This is the first difficulty that our machine learning model has to surmount. There is already an excellent discussion of this problem on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380303/keras-making-a-neural-network-to-find-a-numbers-modulus) which you should read before continuing this post any further.

Hopefully you aren't reading this unless you poked through the linked post. Note that the best solutions use recurrent neural networks (RNN), with the motivation explained in the accepted answer:

> Please understand that this solution is a bit of a tongue-in-cheek thing, because it is based on the task-domain knowledge that our target function can be defined by a simple recurring formula on the sequence of input bits.

In reality, if we aren't using domain knowledge for this problem (for instance, if you're designing your model to play a dice game) then the model might not be able to learn the $x$ mod $m$ function. You could test this by using your model architecture and applying it to this problem directly to see if you can get good results.

### Cost Functions and Convexity

Okay, so maybe learning $x$ mod $m$ is difficult, but as the stackoverflow answer above demonstrates, it is doable. So what's the next hurdle? Let's talk about the training of a model, i.e. the finding of the parameters that best fit the data.

The "magic" of modern machine learning is very much reliant on the fact that convex optimization techniques like gradient descent seem to "just work" even when applied to non-convex optimization problems. They don't work perfectly, and often require a fair amount of tinkering to train properly, but they can still get good results. One of the reasons for this "magic" is that lots of cost functions, while non-convex, aren't *that* non-convex. For example, your cost function might look something like:

[image]

This cost function might look bad at first glance, but notice that it has some degree of regularity/smoothness. You can still tell that the underlying function is continuous because "small" movements along the $x$ or $y$-axis result in "small" changes in height. You can also pick out a general basin-shaped structure, and it's believable that a convex optimization algorithm with some random perturbations could eventually find the global minimum.

Essentially, a cost function with some regularity might not be convex, but can still be "locally convex" in some sense. This means that gradient descent can find a local minimum if the initial point is within a locally convex "basin." In other words, being close the minimum counts for something, so "partial" correctness can be rewarded.

Indeed, this is the idea behind transfer learning. Finding a good minimum for one task that is sufficiently similar to another task can provide the second task with a good initial point and then convex optimization can fine-tune the result to find a nearby minimum for the second task.

### An Experiment

However, the cost function for trying to learn a PRNG has virtually ***no*** regularity whatsoever. It shouldn't come as a shock, but the cost function behaves like noise. But don't take my word for it: let's do an experiment to try to predict the output of Java's PRNG.

For this experiment, **we're going to cheat as much as possible and still lose.** To start with, instead of using some kind of neural network or other machine learning model with a large number of parameters, we're going to use the exact functional form that we know Java's PRNG takes:

$$X_{n + 1} = (a X_n + c) \text{ mod } m$$

which has parameters $a$, $c$, $m$, and $X_0$. This completely sidesteps the difficulty of learning $x$ mod $m$ discussed above. And our model has only four parameters! Modern machine learning algorithms can have hundreds of millions of parameters that require training, so just four should be a piece of cake, right?

Let's make it *even easier* though: suppose that an oracle (no pun intended) tells us three of four correct parameters for Java's PRNG, and our task is simply to learn the value of the fourth. Learning one parameter can't be that hard, right?

Here's some Julia code to emulate Java's PRNG and to plot an $\ell_2$ cost function over each of the four slices of the four slices we get from not knowing one of the four parameters:

```
using LinearAlgebra: norm
using Plots
theme(:dark)
seed = 12150615 # Date the Magna Carta was signed

# Constants used by Java's linear congruential PRNG
a = 25214903917
c = 11
m = 2^48

"""Generates the next integer in a sequence of pseudo-random_sequence
numbers in a linear congruential sequence."""
function next(x, a, c, m)
    return mod(a*x + c, m)
end

"""Generates a random sequence of M random integers from a linear
congruential sequence with the parameters a, c, m, and seed."""
function random_sequence(a, c, m, seed, M)
    nums = zeros(Int, M)
    nums[1] = seed
    for i = 2:M
        nums[i] = next(nums[i-1], a, c, m)
    end
    return nums
end

# Generate Java's random sequence
y = random_sequence(a, c, m, seed, M)

i_values = -200:200 # Range around the correct parameter to test
n_trials = length(i_values)

# Test a neighborhood of the a-values
as = [a + i for i = i_values]
avg_errors = []
for i = 1:n_trials
    # Generate another random sequence using random constants a, b, c, and a random seed
    y_test = random_sequence(as[i], c, m, seed, M)
    avg_error = norm(y_test - y) / M
    push!(avg_errors, avg_error)
end
plot(avg_errors, size=(400, 400), legend=false)

# Test a neighborhood of the c-values
cs = [c + i for i = i_values]
avg_errors = []
for i = 1:n_trials
    # Generate another random sequence using random constants a, b, c, and a random seed
    y_test = random_sequence(a, cs[i], m, seed, M)
    avg_error = norm(y_test - y) / M
    push!(avg_errors, avg_error)
end
plot(avg_errors, size=(400, 400), legend=false, ylim=(1.145e11, 1.151e11))

# Test a neighborhood of the m-values
ms = [m + i for i = i_values]
avg_errors = []
for i = 1:n_trials
    # Generate another random sequence using random constants a, b, c, and a random seed
    y_test = random_sequence(a, c, ms[i], seed, M)
    avg_error = norm(y_test - y) / M
    push!(avg_errors, avg_error)
end
plot(avg_errors, size=(400, 400), legend=false, ylim=(1.145e11, 1.151e11))

# Test a neighborhood of the seed-values
seeds = [seed + i for i = i_values]
avg_errors = []
for i = 1:n_trials
    # Generate another random sequence using random constants a, b, c, and a random seed
    y_test = random_sequence(a, c, m, seeds[i], M)
    avg_error = norm(y_test - y) / M
    push!(avg_errors, avg_error)
end
plot(avg_errors, size=(400, 400), legend=false, ylim=(1.147e11, 1.151e11))
```

[image]

So you can clearly see that even with three of the four parameters and the exact functional form known, the cost function still has the form $c + (\text{noise})$ where $c$ is a constant. In this case, a gradient-descent-type algorithm would compute a gradient of $0 + (\text{noise})$. Then gradient descent is simply performing a random walk. While possible that a random walk could converge to correct parameters, it is extremely unlikely given that the size of the space is $10^{77}$ (see below). Without any regularity, convex optimization tools are no better than a random walk looking for that one "valley" in the middle of each graph where the correct parameter lies.

### Conclusion

It turns out that even with all of this simplification, the last step is still virtually impossible. "Learning" the last parameter boils down to a brute force search over the entire range of possible values for the parameters, because the "magic" of applying convex optimization techniques to train a machine learning model does not help solve a search problem when the cost function does not have any information whatsoever about the direction of even a good local minimum. If you wanted to try every possible 64-bit integer for the four parameters, this would mean searching through $(2^{64})^4 = 2^{256} \approx 10^{77}$ combinations. And this is just for a very simple PRNG.

Ultimately, if you really want to alleviate any worries you might have about your particular task, you could always drop the board game aspect and see if your model can learn the output of the pseudo-random dice roll using your programming language's PRNG. Good luck (you're going need it)!

### Technical Appendix

First, I want to point out that the function $x$ mod $m$ being difficult to approximate is more of an interesting side note, relevant mostly for the concern in the original question that a machine learning algorithm might *incidentally* discover how to predict the output of the PRNG while being trained for some other purpose. The fact is that it is difficult even when this is one's sole purpose. **Difficult, but not unreasonably difficult**. You don't need to appeal to universal approximation theorem to claim this is possible, because in the linked stackoverflow post from above there are several examples of models that successful approximated $x$ mod $m$ (albeit with the input in binary-vector representation). So not only was it possible to represent the function $x$ mod $m$ by a neural network (which is all the UAT guarantees), they were also able to successfully find weights that worked (which is not guaranteed).

Second, what is the technical meaning of the claim that the cost function  has the form
$$
C(x) = \begin{cases}
\text{constant} + \text{noise}, & \text{ if } x \ne x^* \\
0, & \text{ if } x = x^*
\end{cases} 
$$
where $x$ denotes the parameters $x = (a, c, m, \text{seed})$ and $x^*$ denotes the correct parameters? This can be defined technically by picking a radius $\delta > 0$ and then computing the average value
$$
\text{Avg} (\delta, t) = \frac{1}{m(B_\delta (t))}\int_{B_\delta (t)} C(x) dx
$$
where $K$ can represent either $\mathbb{Z}^4$ or $\mathbb{R}^4$, $m$ is either the Lebesgue measure or the counting measure respectively, and $B_\delta (t) = \{ x \in K: \| x - t \| < \delta \}$ is the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $t \in K$. Now the claim that $C = \text{constant} + \text{noise}$ means that as $\delta$ increases, the local average $\text{Avg} (\delta, t)$ converges quickly to a constant $L$, so long as the true parameters $x^* \notin B_\delta (t)$. Here, I say "quickly" to rule out the fact that eventually this limit would be constant after surpassing the bounds of the domain. This definition makes sense even though the "noise" term is technically deterministic. In other words, local averages of $C$ are globally constant. Local averaging smooths out the noise term, and what remains is a constant.

Plotted below is a much larger scale experiment on the interval $[-9 \times 10^{12}, 9 \times 10^{12}]$ that shows essentially the same phenomenon as before. For this experiment, I only tested the case where the seed is unknown as this experiment took a much longer. Each point here is not the cost function, but the local average $\text{Avg} (100, t)$ of the cost function, which smooths out some of the noise:

[image]

Here I've plotted the constant as well, which turns out to be roughly
$$
\text{constant} = 1.150 \times 10^{12}
$$

**Ultimately, this is a problem for gradient-based optimization methods not because of the noise term per se, but because the cost function is "flat." Of course, when you do add in the noise term, a flat function plus noise makes an extremely large number of local minima that certainly doesn't help the convergence of any gradient-based optimization algorithm.**

Moreover, I am well aware that this is an empirical claim, and I can not prove it analytically. I just wanted to demonstrate empirically that the gradient for this function is essentially 0 on average, and contains no information about the direction of $x^*$. In Experiment 1, the neighborhood was purposefully small to demonstrate that even if you started close to $x^*$, there is no visible gradient pointing in that direction. The four slices of the neighborhood $B_{200} (x^*)$ are small, but still don't show a local "basin" (locally approximately convex region) of the sort that gradient-based optimization is good at minimizing in.  Experiment 2 demonstrates this same phenomenon on a much larger scale.

The last technical detail I want to touch on is the fact that I am only analyzing the the model and the cost function as functions over a subset of the domain $\mathbb{Z}^4$, not over $\mathbb{R}^4$. **This means that the gradient/derivative is not defined**. So how can I claim something about the convergence or non-convergence of a gradient-based method when gradients aren't defined? Well, we can of course try fitting a differentiable model defined on $\mathbb{R}^4$ to the data, and compute its derivative, but if the data is already "flat" a model that fits it well will be "flat" as well.

This is not something that I can prove, but I can prove that it is unprovable by constructing a continuously differentiable ($\mathcal{C}^1$) interpolation function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to the cost function data $C(x)$ that would cause gradient descent to converge to the true global minimizer $x^*$ in **one step** with high probability. This is an absurd example, but it demonstrates that trying to prove that gradient-based algorithms couldn't conceivably work here is impossible. To construct the interpolating function, consider two adjacent points $n, n+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ with cost function values $C(n)$ and $C(n+1)$. Pick a threshold $\epsilon > 0$. Now, on the interval $[n + \epsilon, n + 1 - \epsilon]$, we can construct $f$ so that a regular gradient-descent step will reach $x^*$ in one step, i.e. $x^* = x - f'(x)$. This defines an easy differential equation that we can solve as follows:
\begin{align}
x^* & = x - f'(x) \\
\int x^* dx & = \int x - f'(x) dx \\
x x^* & = \frac{1}{2} x^2 - f(x) + D\\
f(x) & = \frac{1}{2} x^2 - x x^* + D
\end{align}
for any constant $D$. The constant is irrelevant, because regardless of its value, we can still define $f$ in such a way on the intevals $[n, n + \epsilon)$ and $(n+1-\epsilon, n+1]$ to make $f \in \mathcal{C}^1$ and such that $C(n)$ and $C(n+1)$ are the correct values, using splines for instance. This construction can be repeated on all intervals and the results can be stitched together in a $\mathcal{C}^1$ manner (using splines again, as one particular method). The result will be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function that interpolates the cost function at all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (so it fits the data here perfectly well), and one which will converge to $x^*$ in one step of the gradient descent algorithm with probability $1 - 2\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon > 0$ to be as small as desired.

Comment: Except all of these functions are continuous because they are functions on $\mathbb{Z}$. And I don't have a good term for "degrees of convexity" other than to say something about the extent to which a convex optimization algorithm works or does not work on a function. But I think it is clear that a functions like the cost function here cannot be optimized using anything other than brute force. There's no local regularity to take advantage of.

Comment: This experiment does not demonstrate that $(aX_n + c) \mod m$ cannot be well-approximated using machine learning -- the deficiency you've found could plausibly be due to a deficiency of experimental design, and unrelated to the modulus function. You'll have to make an appeal to a relevant theorem to conclusively show why machine learning is not appropriate.

Comment: Moreover, the universal approximation theorem **does apply** to discontinuous functions, so long as they are Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Is the modulus function Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: It's a bounded function on a bounded domain (since the domain consists of 64-bit integers), so yes.

Comment: So it sounds like you can write an explanation of why and how to apply theorems to this machine learning problem.

Comment: What theorems are you talking about? There is no general theory for non-convex optimization, as has already been proven by the No Free Lunch Theorem. Any appeal to theory in non-convex optimization in machine learning usually relies on the convex optimization theory and the empirical fact that many non-convex functions still have some degree of regularity like I discussed in my answer. I have plotted the cost function and shown visibly that there is no such regularity here (and what possible experimental design flaws could there be in looking at a graph?)

Comment: There are lots of "bumpy" loss functions. You show a graph of one, but say that it's not "too bumpy." How do we know this? Also, a neural network with dropout has a different bumpy loss every iteration, yet we can still make progress. For lcm modulus, how do we know that this loss function is "too bumpy"? How do we know when a problem has enough "regularity" to be learnable? What does "regularity" of a loss function mean, and how do we know when it's present?

Comment: "Bumpiness" is not the inherent problem, as I explained with the first image which is certainly "bumpy." Appropriate optimization algorithms can optimize bumpy functions such as the Rastrigin function quite well. The problem here is that the cost function is of the form constant + noise, which then makes the gradient 0 + noise, and in turn gradient descent becomes a random walk. A random walk on a space of the size $10^{77}$ is extremely unlikely to ever find the global minimum. In problems where gradient-descent-type algorithms work, the gradient still provides some information.

Comment: Did you generate that loss function plot with a real model?

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure what you mean by a "real" model here. The cost function plotted is comparing the true function with a model of the same functional form which already knows 3 out of the 4 true parameters. Using the exact same functional form is "cheating" in a sense because the original question was asking if a machine learning model designed for some other task could learn the output of the PRNG used to train it, but that simply means that this is a better/more accurate model than one that has to learn the functional form in addition to the parameters.

Comment: Usually "noise" is used to mean that there's some component of the data that is random, such as adding iid draws from some distribution to the target variable. Since lcm modulus is completely deterministic, you must have a different meaning for "noise." Can you clarify your meaning? // If I try to unify these comments together, it seems that you're saying that because lcm mod is Lebesgue integrable, then the UAT does apply, but because the UAT does not comment on how to obtain the weights for any particular problem, this task is very challenging from an optimization perspective. Is that fair?

Comment: A coin flip is completely determined by the physics of the process that flips it, and yet it is the quintessential random event. If it helps you understand what's going on here, think of "noise" similar to the decomposition of a time series into a "signal" or "trend" component and a noise term. The gradient of the cost function here has zero signal component and only a noise component.

Comment: There is a subtlety here. All of these functions are over $\mathbb{Z}$ and don't have a gradient, so the gradient to which I'm referring is really the gradient of the cost function for a model over $\mathbb{R}$ fitted to the process. You sound like you expect there to be a proof that a convex optimization algorithm won't converge to the global minimum, but this is obviously impossible. For one, the initial values could already be at the global minimum. Secondly, there will always be an interpolating function with the exact right gradient to reach the global minimum on the first step.

Comment: And I'm not referring to the UAT at all: you're the one that brought it up for some reason. The UAT is a result from approximation theory, but the whole point of talking about the cost functions for the oracle model is that we don't need a machine learning algorithm to learn the functional form of the generating process for the PRNG, and so we don't need to talk about approximation at all. If the problem is virtually impossible even without having to approximate the form of the function, why would it be easier to solve when you also don't know the functional form?

Comment: This is a great argument, and well explored from end to end. The one little linchpin for which I'm unsatisfied is the following line: _"I'm then going to appeal to intuition to claim that, if we don't have to worry about a machine learning algorithm learning how to predict the output of a very simple PRNG with poor statistical properties, we probably don't have to worry about it learning how to predict the output of a fancy PRNG with better statistical properties."_ There are some really hard problems that turn out to be far easier than many easy problems, when you just know the right approach

Comment: @ericperkerson It seems that if you're proposing a model of a function in $\mathbb{Z}$, but doing so using $\mathbb{R}$ as a substitute for $\mathbb{Z}$, and then finding that the model using $\mathbb{R}$ is insufficient to the task. Your explanation about "noise" and employment of gradient descent seems to further obscure the issue, especially when you acknowledge that functions over $\mathbb{Z}$ don't have gradients, and don't articulate what "noise" means in this setting. So, the question remains, "Why would we expect this experiment to succeed? How do we know that its a reasonable test?"

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to bridge the gap; using the UAT seemed to be a promising avenue due to your assurances that the modulus function is lebesgue integrable so we can deploy a UAT to approximate modulus. You say that UAT is not the point, which is fine, my spitball suggestion could have been misguided. But even though you're using the oracle function here, the complications in my previous comment seem to undermine this experiment's validity. Why should we believe you've shown that ML can't be applied to modulus, as opposed to concluding that this particular experiment is a poor model?

Comment: I have an intuition -- possibly an incorrect one -- that ML isn't useful to recover parameters of this modulus function for some reason -- such as it's a function $\mathbb{Z}^4 \to \mathbb{Z}$, or it's discontinuous, or it doesn't have gradients, or some other fact about it. Maybe there is no such theorem which excludes this modulus function from approximation with ML. But trying one experiment, and finding that it doesn't work, does not seem to be sufficient evidence. It will require more development of why this experiment is the best way to recover the desired parameters.

Comment: In other words, each UAT lays out a set of requirements on the function you want to approximate, and then says that you can approximate such functions using some number of neurons or some number of layers. Analogously, I'm asking "What are the requirements on functions which can be approximated with your experiment here?" If modulus doesn't satisfy these requirements, then we know from the start that the experiment is hopeless, no computations necessary.

Comment: @Sycorax Please see the edit to my answer. The approximation of the modulus is a side note to the main point. We could of course simply use the modulus function as the activation function and the difficulty would still remain in minimizing the cost function.

Comment: @Tal Yes, I understand your point. But this is very much an claim that requires empirical testing, and so for different PRNGs you would need to test them similarly. But I can't test every PRNG myself. If you had a particular example in mind I could try emulating it as well and analyzing the cost function in the same manner as above.

Comment: The *presumption* that modulus can serve as an activation function has not been established, so we return to my core question: Why is your experiment valid? And if there is a reason that your experiment is valid, then it should be simple enough to name it. That is, why should we trust gradient descent of functions without gradients?

Comment: Because it shows how flat the cost function is, which implies that the data itself contains no gradient information about the direction of the global minimizer $x^*$. I don't need to have a continuous model (or an activation function) to show this, so you're not addressing my main point at all. Also, I can directly use $f(x) = (ax + c) \text{ mod } m$, which uses a composition of an affine function and a nonlinear activation function as a model. Who's to say that this isn't a model?

Comment: The experiment is not a proof, just like all experiments. I'm not claiming that it is. And the last part of the appendix proves that there exists a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function interpolating the cost function that does converge using gradient descent, so one cannot prove that a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function couldn't exist where gradient descent would converge.

Comment: @Sycorax Would the following experiment convince you: Suppose I construct a continuous extension $g$ of the $x$ mod $m$ function to use as an activation function, and then use the model $g(ax + c)$ to compute the gradients. If the gradients point uniformly in every direction with a symmetric distribution of magnitudes, would that be enough? In this case, gradient descent would be a random walk. Surely you wouldn't argue that a random walk could reasonably be expected to find the global minimizer?

Comment: Your proof begs the question because it depends on knowing the minimizer $x^*$ ahead of time to construct $f$. The point of gradient descent is to find $x^*$ which is unknown. // You point out that the SO models of $x \text{mod} m$ are "successful," so the experimental model seems poorly chosen to demonstrate that $x \text{mod} m$ is difficult to approximate. Because these models are "successful," it seems we *do* need to worry about prng prediction in a general setting, because certain models can recover it. // Only the "incidental discovery" portion addresses what OP asks about & it's 1 line

Comment: "Your proof begs the question because it depends on knowing the minimizer ∗ ahead of time to construct ." That's the whole point. I'm saying that a gradient-descent based method is unlikely to minimize the cost function here. I'm also saying that this is not something that I can prove because it's possible to construct that example. You seem to be saying that we should worry about something like that example to be possible, and I'm saying that it's ridiculous. I think you now understand that it's ridiculous, so we agree.

Comment: There's still a logical gap here. The observation that your gradient-descent method on this problem is "ridiculous" isn't able to account for why the SO models are "successful." What accounts for this discrepancy? Are you saying that the SO models are just exceptionally lucky -- lucky enough to overcome the "ridiculous" conditions in your proof? Or is it simply the case that the model you chose to demonstrate this point was doomed from the start because the model is ridiculous? Or is there something else that accounts for the difference?